# Is list comprehension implemented via map and lambda function?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-internals

According to the [list comprehension doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34835951/9758790): `squares = [x**2 for x in range(10)]` is equivalent to  `squares = list(map(lambda x: x**2, range(10)))`

But does Python actually implement list comprehension via `map` and `lambda`? Or is the `squares = list(map(lambda x: x**2, range(10)))` in the document just an approximation instead of exactly equivalence?

- If so, how to deal with iterating an `enumerate` object? For example, `squares = [(idx, x**2) for idx, x in enumerate(range(10))]`? I find it hard for me to imitate the previous example and re-write it using `map` and `lambda`.
- If not(I tend to this option but not sure), is the list comprehension is implemented separately? Is there anything python sentence that is exactly equivalent to the list comprehension?

---

My research effort:

I tried `squares = [print(locals()) for x in range(1)]` vs `squares = list(map(lambda x: print(locals()), range(1)))`, inspried by this question [eval fails in list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45194934/9758790). The first one will give `{'.0': <range_iterator object at 0x000002AB976C4430>, 'x': 0}` while the latter gives `{'x': 0}`. Perhaps this indicates that they are not exactly equivalence.

I also found these question:

1. [Where are list comprehensions implemented in CPython source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281997/where-are-list-comprehensions-implemented-in-cpython-source-code)
2. [How does List Comprehension exactly work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941643/how-does-list-comprehension-exactly-work-in-python)
3. [List comprehension vs map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map)

They are using Python assembly to show the behavior of list comprehension. These answers perhaps indicate that the list comprehension is implemented separately.

So I tend to believe that the list comprehension is not implemented by `map` and `lambda`. However, I am not sure, and want to know "is there anything python sentence that is exactly equivalent to the list comprehension" as I mentioned above.

---

The origin of this question:

I am trying to [answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72989694/9758790). I want to explain strange behaviors related to the list comprehension without using python assembly. I used to think the list comprehension is implemented via `lambda` in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72335248/9758790). However, I am doubting about this now.

Comment: List comprehensions are their own thing, `list(map(...))` is just an equivalent with the same _output_ (and is specifically discouraged by https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists). It's similar to the pure-Python equivalents listed in [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), they're just to show the behaviour, the real work happens in the underlying implementation (in C, for CPython - maybe in e.g. PyPy they're more closely aligned).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually it looks like the real work for listcomps happens during compilation (so yes, well, in C, but that's beside the point and PyPy does the same anyway) – the body of a listcomp is just turned into a function that technically accepts 1 argument (the iterable) and outputs a list. Which is pretty cool, imo :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I prefer my previous version of this question. Would you mind me doing rollback? It takes me lot of time to format it.  I really like to divide my post to several parts, I think it makes my post look clearer. And I also want "why I want to ask so" to be at the last of my post since it is not very closed to what I want to ask, but provide some additional information.

Comment: Yes, I would. If nothing else, you were using quote formatting on things that didn't appear to be quotes. Starting with the context helps people understand the frame before getting into the details. And the headings (although this is more of a preference) just take up lots vertical height - if you feel you need to highlight "this is where my question is", you should probably try to be more concise instead.

Comment: Also you've accepted an answer with the same "Python assembly" you'd already dismissed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6407222/3001761, so closing to send the next viewer to the fuller set of answers there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, list comprehensions are not implemented by map and lambda under the hood, not in CPython and not in Pypy3 either.

[CPython (3.9.13 here) compiles the list comprehension into a special code object that outputs a list](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c22f134211743cd5ad14cec1dd4f527bee542b4c/Python/compile.c#L5103-L5122) and calls it as a function:

```
~ $ echo 'x = [a + 1 for a in [1, 2, 3, 4]]' | python3 -m dis
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x107446f50, file "<stdin>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ((1, 2, 3, 4))
              8 GET_ITER
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 STORE_NAME               0 (x)
             14 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x107446f50, file "<stdin>", line 1>:
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                12 (to 18)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (a)
              8 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
             12 BINARY_ADD
             14 LIST_APPEND              2
             16 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Whereas the equivalent `list(map(lambda: ...))` thing is just function calls:

```
~ $ echo 'x = list(map(lambda a: a + 1, [1, 2, 3, 4]))' | python3 -m dis
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (list)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (map)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <lambda> at 0x102701f50, file "<stdin>", line 1>)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<lambda>')
              8 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             10 BUILD_LIST               0
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 ((1, 2, 3, 4))
             14 LIST_EXTEND              1
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             20 STORE_NAME               2 (x)
             22 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <lambda> at 0x102701f50, file "<stdin>", line 1>:
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: So the `list(map(lambda: ...))` build a `lambda` object and call it iteratively, while the list comprehension will build a `listcomp` function that handles iteration and call this listcomp` function once. Am I correct?

Comment: Yep, that's correct – `map` will call the (lambda) function internally for each element, with all of the overhead involved in function calls, while the generated `listcomp` function is equivalent to `x = []; for a in y: x.append(...); return x` (though more efficiently still, as `x.append` doesn't take a lookup to do).